# How do I solve the fatal error for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have updated the version of wordpress, and my webpage has not been working all of a sudden.
I have debugged to see what the problem is, and I could not understand any of the explanation that is written. I have spent hours trying figure out what it meant, and still could not grasp what I have to change and add. Could someone please explain what it means, and what I must do in order to fix this? Is there an instruction written in the notice & error?

```
Notice: date.php is deprecated since version 5.3.0! Use wp-includes/class-wp-date-query.php instead. in /home/vol10_1/epizy.com/epiz_24728949/htdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4719

Notice: class-oembed.php is deprecated since version 5.3.0! Use wp-includes/class-wp-oembed.php instead. in /home/vol10_1/epizy.com/epiz_24728949/htdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4719

Notice: Undefined property: wpdb::$blog_versions in /home/vol10_1/epizy.com/epiz_24728949/htdocs/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 659

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function '_wp_add_additional_image_sizes' not found or invalid function name in /home/vol10_1/epizy.com/epiz_24728949/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 288

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Block_Styles_Registry' not found in /home/vol10_1/epizy.com/epiz_24728949/htdocs/wp-includes/script-loader.php:2899 Stack trace: #0 /home/vol10_1/epizy.com/epiz_24728949/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(288): enqueue_block_styles_assets('') #1 /home/vol10_1/epizy.com/epiz_24728949/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(312): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #2 /home/vol10_1/epizy.com/epiz_24728949/htdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 /home/vol10_1/epizy.com/epiz_24728949/htdocs/wp-includes/script-loader.php(2853): do_action('enqueue_block_a...') #4 /home/vol10_1/epizy.com/epiz_24728949/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(288): wp_common_block_scripts_and_styles('') #5 /home/vol10_1/epizy.com/epiz_24728949/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(312): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #6 /home/vol10_1/epizy.com/epiz_24728949/htdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #7 /home/vol10_1/epizy.com/epiz_24728949/htdocs/wp-includes/script- in /home/vol10_1/epizy.com/epiz_24728949/htdocs/wp-includes/script-loader.php on line 2899

There has been a critical error on your website.
```

Comment: On what version of php is the website running and which Wordpres version did you update to?

Comment: @matthijsknigge Hello! I have tried updating to Wordpress version 5.3 and my php version is 7.3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the update went wrong and some files got corrupted.

You can try this to fix it:

1. Download a new Wordpress installation zip
   https://wordpress.org/download/
2. Remove the folders wp-admin & wp-includes from your server
3. Reupload those folders from the fresh downloaded Wordpress zip

*Note: this does not delete your site content, the content of your website is in the database and in the wp-content folder.*

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your kind advice. One quick question: if I remove the current wp-admin and wp-includes from my server and reupload from the downloaded zip, wouldn't the contents on my website all disappear? :(

Comment: No the content of your site is in the database and in the wp-content folder @YaeLee

Comment: doesn't work for me. `Notice: date.php is deprecated since version 5.3.0! Use wp-includes/class-wp-date-query.php instead. in C:\web\site-dev\wp-includes\functions.php on line 4719`
`

Comment: hi @dewd i got same problem do you found have solution?

Comment: @Sanjay I think I deleted wp-includes and wp-admin and copied from newest WordPress. When I loaded, the system did a db upgrade and was then ok.

Answer (score 1):

Your wordpress version 5.3 need php 7.4 version to be runned properly

so you need to upgrade your php version

or downgrade you wordpress version to 5.2 and disable wordpress auto update

```
// wp-configs.php    
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );
```

Answer (score 0):

**PHP Version 7.2.18-1
WordPress  5.2.4**

I am running 5 sites on same environment

you need to update your PHP version and use a stable WordPress version